# C# Observable delay until certain condition met

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observablecollection

I'm currently implementing an autocomplete which triggers a search on a web service when a user enters a text.

```
textChange.Subscribe(this.TextChanged);
```

Additionally I have a property in my class indicating if a search is running `IsRunning`.

Now I want to buffer the user input while `IsRunning==true` and fire the `TextChange` method only if `IsRunning==false` with newly entered text.

Could you help me out?

Edit: Sample code to get the idea without using reactive:

```
    public class AutoComplete
    {
        private bool isRunning;
        private string textBuffer;


        public AutoComplete()
        {
            this.textChanged += this.TextChanged;
        }

        public void TextChanged(string text)
        {
            if (isRunning) textBuffer = text;
            else Search(text);
        }

        public void Search(string text)
        {
            isRunning = true;
            // DoSearch()
            isRunning = false;

            // TODO: Search finished, check if textBuffer was filled and reexecute search with the new termn
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't tried much with Rx yourself I'm just going to give some pointers:

1. Lose the `isRunning` bool, you want to try to keep as little state as possible when using Rx.
2. Use `Select()` to transform the input search string to a Task that performs the search, have the Task return the results.
3. Use `Switch()` to discard all search tasks that are still in progress except for the last search task. See also: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Switch
4. You'll need to transform the search Task into an observable using `Observable.FromAsync()`.
5. Optionally, use `Throttle()` to limit the number of requests (so your server won't be overloaded with requests).

---

Edit: since you don't want multiple searches running at the same time, you'll need to block the stream while a search is running. You'll need to do something like:

```
searchTermStream    
.Select(l => Observable.FromAsync(asyncSearchMethod))
.Concat()
.Subscribe();
```

The `Concat()` operator makes sure a task is only started after the previous one has returned a result.

I predict this is going to feel laggy for the users though, because the searches will take longer than the user needs to enter a new character.

Comment: Thank you very much for these hints. I don't want to have multiple requests at the same time. So if one request is executing I just want to delay the user input until the first one finished and then execute another.

Comment: This will return *every* result though, the OP is looking for intermediate items to be dropped.

Comment: I'd argue there are no intermediate items when you perform the entire algorithm blocking like this, every item is the last item per definition.

Comment: Oh I see, you are assuming that the asyncSearchMethod will grab the latest value of the text box. Still, this won't block, every time the user types it will create a new Observable stream, which will have to be evaluated, you'll just evaluate the last entered string several times.

Comment: Well, I haven't tested this specific piece of code, but have used it several times in the past. It just takes strings from the search term stream as they come in, creates a task for each string, waits for the task to produce a result, then starts a new task. The stream it produces is a list of results from the async method calls. The value can be passed to the task using e.g. `.Select(s => Observable.FromAsync(_ => asyncSearchMethod(s)))`

Comment: Exactly, you've probably used the first part of your answer (which is the accepted way of approaching this problem).  However, when you use `Concat` you have to evaluate all intermediate values, i.e. typing 's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k' will run 5 queries, each one will only start after the previous one *finishes*. In this case the OP wants to have only 's' and 'stack', `Concat` won't drop the intermediate values.